# It's not working after modify after the database connection using php

Tags: php, mysql

It's so weird, after did some modification. The input box is not appearing now and the values are not saving in the database.

What is the correct or right code for this? See below

PHP (add.php)

```
 <?
$contract_num=$_POST['contract_num'];
$random_data=$_POST['random_data'];
$dbh=mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'port')
if (!$dbh) {
die(mysql_error());
}
$db=mysql_select_db("database", $dbh)
if (!$db) 
{ 
die(mysql_error()); 
}
$result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tablename` VALUES ('$contract_num', '$random_data')");
if(!$result) 
{  
die(mysql_error());
}
echo "Your information has been successfully added to the database."; 
?>
```

HTML:

```
<?php
include "add.php";
?>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="contract_num"><br>
<input type="text" name="random_data"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Upload file">
</form>
```

Comment: Why you are including add.php as another file?

Comment: You should stop using mysql_* functions, since they are officially deprecated by PHP. Use something like PDO or MysqlI instead. You can read about PDO From: http://ee1.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: what is the showing error...?

Comment: It display blank white page and the values is not saving in the database

Comment: then first enable your errors, just add this `ini_set("display_errors",true)` to add.php at the top

Comment: I put that but after I save and reload the page, there's no error display

Comment: see my answer query now it's working in my localhost now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make some changes in your code:

1)  Semicolon missing in `$dbh=mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'port');` and `$db=mysql_select_db("test", $dbh);`

2) Change `<?` to `<?php`

3) Try to call the form variables only if it is set. ie, if form is submitted.

```
<?php
/* Write the code for db connection on top */
$dbh=mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'port');
if (!$dbh) {
die(mysql_error());
}
$db=mysql_select_db("database", $dbh);
if (!$db) 
{ 
die(mysql_error()); 
}

if(isset($_POST))   // call POST variables only if it is set
{
$contract_num=$_POST['contract_num'];
$random_data=$_POST['random_data'];
$result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tablename` VALUES ('$contract_num', '$random_data')");
if(!$result) 
{  
die(mysql_error());
}

echo "Your information has been successfully added to the database."; 
}
```

4) Change `include "add.php";` to `include_once "add.php";` to make sure that the file is included only once.

Comment: its not working. After do some changes and reload the page, i get blank page only

Comment: The method you are trying is not right anyway. Are you getting any errors? Is the data getting inserted or not?

Comment: I get blank white page and the values is not insertted in the database

Comment: @User014019..Please try with my answer the main problem was with the `<?` and missing semicolons. I tried your code in my local and is working fine if these changes are made. Let me know.

Comment: After I reload the page, still I get the white blank page

Answer (score 1):

add.php

```
<?php
$contract_num=$_POST['contract_num'];
$random_data=$_POST['random_data'];
$dbh=mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if(!$dbh) {
die(mysql_error());
}
$db=mysql_select_db("database", $dbh);
if (!$db) 
{ 
die(mysql_error()); 
}
$result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO `tablename` (column_1,column_2)VALUES ('$contract_num', '$random_data')");
if(!$result) 
{  
die(mysql_error());
}
echo "Your information has been successfully added to the database."; 
?>
```

**In short**

$result=mysql_query("INSERT INTO yourtablename (colum_1,column_2)VALUES ('$contract_num', '$random_data')");

in short you are missing column name in your query, change column_1 and Column_2, according to your column name, and remove the port from your connection

and give form action="add.php"

```
<?php
include "add.php";
?>

<form action="add.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="contract_num"><br>
<input type="text" name="random_data"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Upload file">
</form>
```

Comment: I get this error after I did changes and reload the page You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''contracts'(column_1,column_2) VALUES ('1234567890', 'sdfghjkolp')' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

In localhost no need to provide port.

```
$dbh=mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password',)
```

In the form use this.

```
<form action="somapage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I had to write my code like this.

```
//give form an action
//I want to php_self so
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER('PHP_SELF'); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
```

Then on my php code I just have to validate if there was a `posted` data

```
<?php
   if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      //do code here 
   }

  //so that on the first run of the page it will not cause an error
 ?>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Or use this it is working in my local server.In your action means targetpage.php use the below code.

```
       if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
         $con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'username', 'password');
            if (!$con)
              {
              die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
              }
            mysql_select_db('database_name', $con);
            $sql="set names 'utf8'";// for unicode support, must use after mysql_select_db() function.
            mysql_query($sql); 
            mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8')or die('charset problem:'.mysql_error());
            mysql_query("SET SESSION collation_connection ='utf8_general_ci'") or die('collation problem:'.mysql_error()); 
            $contract_num=$_POST['contract_num'];
$random_data=$_POST['random_data'];
            $sql="INSERT INTO tablename (contract_num,random_data)
              VALUES 
                ('$contract_num', '$random_data')";
         if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
          {
          die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
          }
    }
```

In the form use this.

```
    <?php
include "add.php";
?>

<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="contract_num"><br>
<input type="text" name="random_data"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload file">
</form>
```